# quiver not drawing arrows just lots of blue, matlab

Tags: matlab

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong with the quiver plotting function when I don't really get arrows, it just fills the empty space with lots of blue.Look at the image below and then look at my code.

This is just a part of my contour since this eats up proccessing power if I try to draw it larger. But my function, the contours and everything else works, it's just the quiver I'm having trouble with.

[image: Matlab plot]

```
interval = -100:100;

[X Y] = meshgrid(interval, interval);

h = figure;
contour(X, Y, Z);

hold on;

[FX,FY] = gradient(-Z);
quiver(X, Y, FX, FY);

hold off;
```

If I make my matrix more sparse, e.g. with "interval = linspace(-800, 1600, 1200);" the result will look like this:
[image]

EDIT:
What I need are contour lines like that, but the arrows should flow with them. Right now these just look like dots, even if I zoom in further. If I zoom out the entire window will be blue.

Here is the script in its entirety if anyone wants to play with it to figure this out.

```
m1 = 1;
m2 = 0.4;
r1 = [1167 0 0];
r2 = [-467 0 0];
G = 9.82;

w = sqrt( G*(m1+m2) / norm(r1-r2)^3 );

interval = linspace(-800, 1600, 1200);

% Element-wise 2-norm
ewnorm = @(x,y) ( x.^2 + y.^2 ).^(1/2);

% Element-wise cross squared
ewcross2 = @(w,x,y) w^2.*( x.*x + y.*y );

[X Y] = meshgrid(interval, interval);

Z = - G*m1 ./ ewnorm( X-r1(1), Y-r1(2) ) - G*m2 ./ ewnorm( X-r2(1), Y-r2(2) ) - 1/2*ewcross2(w,X,Y);

h = figure;
contour(Z);

daspect([1 1 1]);

saveas(h, 'star1', 'eps');

hold on;

[FX,FY] = gradient(-Z);
quiver(X, Y, FX,FY);

hold off;
```

Comment: Just a formula that works because I get expected contours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the mesh is too dense. You only want to have as few elements as necessary to generate a useful mesh. As such, try reducing the density of the mesh:

```
interval = -100:2:100
```

If you're going to be changing the limits often, you probably want to avoid using the `X:Y:Z` formulation. Use the [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) function instead:

```
interval = linspace(-100,100,10);
```

This will ensure that no matter what your limits, your mesh will be `10x10`. In the comment below, you mention that the arrows are appearing as dots when you use a very large mesh. This is to be expected. The arrows reflect "velocity" at a given point. When your plot is scaled out to a very large degree, then the velocity at any given point on the plot will be almost 0, hence the very small arrows. Check out the [`quiver` plot documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quiver.html), as well as the [`quivergroup` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quivergroupproperties.html), to see more details.

If you absolutely must see arrows at a large scale, you can try setting the `AutoScale` property to `off`, or increasing the `AutoScaleFactor`:

```
quiver(X, Y, FX, FY, 'AutoScale', 'off');
quiver(X, Y, FX, FY, 'AutoScaleFactor', 10);
```

You may also want to play with the `MarkerSize` and `MaxHeadSize` properties. I really just suggest looking at all the `QuiverGroup` properties and trying things out.

Comment: If I did -100:20:100 I got reasonable arrows. However, when trying to do the same thing with the interval -800:1600 I didn't have much success... I just got dots.

Comment: @calle - Your new mesh is too dense, see amended answer.

Comment: I added more information to my post. I tried with many different densities but could not solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a threshold

```
interval = -100:100;

[X Y] = meshgrid(interval, interval);

h = figure;
contour(X, Y, Z);

hold on;

[FX,FY] = gradient(-Z);
GM = sqrt(FX.^2 + FY.^2);
threshold = 0.1;
mask = GM > threshold;
quiver(X(mask), Y(mask), FX(mask), FY(mask));

hold off;
```

This will show only vectors with a magnitude > 0.1;