# MATLAB Quiver - Tiny arrows

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot x and y velocities using quiver function in MATLAB.

I have x,y,u and v arrays(with their usual meanings) with dimension 100x100
So, the result is my quiver plot is dense and I cannot see the arrows unless I zoom in.
Somewhat like this: [quiver not drawing arrows just lots of blue, matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435499/quiver-not-drawing-arrows-just-lots-of-blue-matlab)

Take a look at my plot:
[image: My quiver plot]

Is there any way to make quiver plot less dense(and with bigger arrows)? I am planning to clip x-axis range to 0-4. But anything apart from that?

I cannot make my mesh less dense for accuracy concerns. I am, however willing to ignore some fine data points if that's required to make the plot look better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can plot a reduced number of arrows by plotting, for example, (assuming your data are in arrays)

```
quiver(x(1:2:end,1:2:end),y(1:2:end,1:2:end),u(1:2:end,1:2:end),v(1:2:end,1:2:end))
```

where the 2 in this example means we plot only a quarter as many arrows. You can of course change it, as long as you change all of the 2's so that the arrays are all appropriately sized.

If you want to change the length of the arrows there are two options. Firstly, you can use the scale option `scale=2` to scale the arrows by the amount specified, or you can normalise the velocities if you want to have all the arrows the same length. You do lose information doing that, because you can't compare the magnitude of the velocity by looking at the arrows, but it may be useful in some situations. You can do this by dividing `u` and `v` both by `sqrt(u.^2+v.^2)` (at the points you wish to plot arrows at.

Hope that helps and sets everything out nicely.

Comment: Hm...I kinda did the same thing...
but the hard way...by storing the filtered matrix first

Comment: I usually store the filtered matrices too so I can reuse them more easily, but to show what I meant it was simpler to put them straight into the `quiver` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your interval value a bit larger in order to make your matrix more sparse.

This is very dense:

```
1:0.0001:100
```

This is very sparse:

```
1:1:100
```

**EDIT:**

If you have the Image Processing Toolkit you can use the [imresize](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/imresize.html) function to reduce the matrix resolution:

```
newMat = imresize(oldMat, newSize);
```

And if you don't have the Toolbox then you can resize in a similar manner to [this example](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100116033705AAxBoay) using `interp2` Interpolation:

```
orgY = 1:size(oldMat,1); 
orgX = 1:size(oldMat,2); 
[orgX,orgY] = meshgrid(orgX ,orgY); 
newY = linspace(1,size(mat,1),newHeight); 
newX = linspace(1,size(mat,2),newWidth); 
[newX,newY] = meshgrid(newX,newY); 
newMat = interp2(orgX,orgY,mat,newX,newY);
```

And thanks to @David, if you want to just strip out some individual points you can simply do:

```
xPlot=x(1:2:end)
```

Comment: Actually data is coming from Fortran program and I cannot change meshsize there because that will hamper the accuracy. Can I make matlab neglect some fine points? e.g. my current mesh in x&y is 0:0.05:5. Can I make MATLAB consider only points at say 0:0.2:5?

Comment: Yes. You can create new variables like `xPlot=x(1:2:end)`  which will plot arrows at 1/4 of the number of points as just using `x` and `y`.

Comment: If you don't want to lose much information you will need to do some sort of interpolation rather than a straight removal of intermediate points.

Comment: @Samuel no I don't think you will lose information because a quiver arrow only gives information about the point at which it is being plotted. Since quiver only plots where the data is, interpolation isn't necessary.

Comment: I think skipping would be better than interpolation because it will give me exact value at every point as it is. If I interpolate(actually this will be reverse of interpolation), The value at a point will be affected by neighboring points which actually is not the case..

Comment: Alright sounds good, @David did you want to post that answer?