# Removing small values in slice

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

How can I delete the small values in a slice plot? 
In my plot, there is basically too much blue and I cannot see the red points inside.[image]

Or, put slightly differently:

*Is it possible delete some points in a slice plot with matlab?

slice(X,Y,Z,V,sx,sy,sz) represents the value of the volume V on the whole plans defined by sx,sy and sz. But can I choose to keep some points of these plans only?

- Do we have to represent the values of V on the whole plan?
- Can I make "small values" transparent?

**EDIT**
New code:

```
h =slice(x,y,z,V,sx,sy,sz);
for n=1:length(h)
    set(h(n), 'alphadata',get(h(n),'cdata'), 'facealpha','flat');   
end
a = alphamap('rampup',256);
a(a<(threshold)) = 0;
a(a>(threshold)) = 0.07;
alphamap(a);
```

I tried with the code above. However, this is the plot I am getting:
I think there is a problem with cdata (the colors) but I can't figure out what this is...

[image]

Comment: Can you just plot less points, similar to this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675089/matlab-quiver-tiny-arrows/19694936#19694936)

Comment: @David I tried something like this by increasing the space between the slice plans, but I need to see 'details' of my red points because it varies rapidly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the transparency so lower values are more transparent.  First, you need the handles to your slices:

`h = slice(X,Y,Z,V,sx,sy,sz);`

`h` is not a single handle but a series of handles to the different slices.  For any one handle you can change the transparency (or loop around for all n to change them all):

`set(h(n),'alphadata',get(h(n),'cdata'),'facealpha','flat')`;

`alphadata` is the data for transparency - by default this is "1" (opaque), so instead for each handle you can set it to the contents of `cdata`.  `AlphaDataMapping` should already be set to `scaled` by default - so the values in `alphadata` are mapped to an alphamap, just as `cdata` values are mapped to your colormap (more on that later).

`facealpha` is a setting for how the alphadata is applied to the faces of an object - needs to be changed so that the values in alphadata are actually used.

If you want to adjust how transparent values are or which are transparent, you can change the alphamap. The default map is just linear and can be seen by `plot(get(gcf,'Alphamap'))`, where is 0 = invisible and 1 = opaque.  The length of the map can vary so you have a lot of freedom in adjusting it - for example you can completely zero out the lower part if you're not interested in those values:

```
a = alphamap('rampup',256);
a(1:80)=0;
alphamap(a); % only changes alphamap of current figure
```

Read more about transparency in Matlab [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/visualize/making-objects-transparent.html).

Comment: This is a great answer thanks! I just have few questions: why would you loop around all n? Is it to define different transparencies for each slice? If I understand correctly, it is possible to make transparent some points by setting their alphamap to 0 (in your example, the 80 smallest values will be 0). So if I want to map that to my function V, I could define a threshold t for this function (discard the points for which V<t) by putting to 0 the points of the alphamap a that are such that: a<(t/256)?

Comment: Yes, each slice has its own handle - h(1)...h(n) where n is the number of slices, and each has to be set separately - so each point in the slice has a cdata value (sets color) and an alphadata value (sets transparency).  And yes again on the thresholding - alternatively you could use `alim([amin amax])` which works pretty much like `clim` - so if you set `amin` to your threshold then all the values below that would be 0 (using the default alphamap) and all the values above `amax` would be set to 1.  Editing the alphamap is more flexible, though.

Comment: I edited my code, but I think there is a problem with the colors?

Comment: 1. At least some of your alpha values need to be close to 1 or the whole thing will be transparent. 0.07 is tiny. 2. you want to set a to zero based on the position in the alphamap, not the values contained within a.  Something along the lines of `thresh = floor(t/256); a(1:thresh)=0;` should work, you shouldn't need to change the higher values.