# Remove Specific Values in MatLab Slices by making them transparent

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

I have a similar question to what was asked here "[Removing small values in slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720241/removing-small-values-in-slice)". I would like to make specific colors of cylindrical slices transparent, and I think I can use `alphamap` in MatLab.

Here is my figure showing the cylindrical slices. I know the indices of each of the transitions in my colorbar.

- At -4: `nN2` for blue to cyan
- At -3: `nN1` for cyan to white
- At  0: `n0` for white
- At  3: `nP1` for white to yellow
- At  4: `nP1` for yellow to red

So far I created an alphamap like this

```
Lia = ismember(cmap,[1 1 1],'rows');    % cmap is the color map
alpha_map = double((~Lia)');
```

But when I try to apply this alphamap to a single slice nothing happens.

```
for r=1:length(RoLoc)
   Vsli{q,i,r}.AlphaData = alpha_map;  % Vsli{q,i,r} is individual surface
end
```

I also get an error when I try to change `FaceAlpha` of one surface to 'interp' or 'flat', saying the size of the matrix is not large enough. Not sure what that is referring to.

If you could offer any help I would appreciate it, and if you need information please comment and let me know.

I'm using version R2018b of MatLab.

[image: Slices]

**Update: Here is small part of the script to make the surfaces**
*I cannot upload my actual data because they are too big so in this sample I am using the built in flow data from MatLab.*

```
Ny = 1000;
[X,Y,Z,V] = flow(10);

y = [-0.7344,0.7031];
AoAd = 45;
delta = 1/2*cosd(AoAd);
dt = 0.0258;  % Size of time step
dtheta = 7.5;  % Differential angle size [deg]
theta = 180 + dtheta;
iso = -3;

AR = 5;
RoLoc = 0.5*AR;
% don't bother to draw the rectangular patch in the image

F = figure;
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
hold on

fh = gcf();
axh = findall(fh, 'Type', 'Axes');

sweep = floor(2.1*Ny*RoLoc);
[Xc,Yc,Zc] = cylinder2(RoLoc*ones(1,Ny),[0,1,0],sweep);      % you can find this here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64007-generate-cylinder-with-custom-axis

 H = [1 0 0 0;
   0 1 0 min(y);   % vertical translation
   0 0 1 0;
   0 0 0 1]*...
   [1 0 0 0;
   0 peak2peak(y) 0 0;   % vertical stretching
   0 0 1 0;
   0 0 0 1]*...
   [ones(1,Ny);Yc(:,1)';ones(1,Ny);ones(1,Ny)];

 Yc = repmat(H(2,1:Ny)',1,sweep+1);
 clear H

 % angle for part of the cylinder
 Phi_prime = atand(delta/RoLoc);
 theta_prime = linspace(360,0,sweep+1)';

 T = 6;
 theta_q = theta - T*Phi_prime;
 theta_p = theta + 2*Phi_prime;

 [~,l] = min(abs(theta_prime - theta_p));
 [~,m] = min(abs(theta_prime - theta_q));

 Vsli = slice(axh,X,Y,Z,V,Xc(:,l:m),Yc(:,l:m),Zc(:,l:m),'linear');
 Vsli.EdgeColor = 'none';

 % Setup color axis range
 V_min = sign(min(caxis))*ceil(abs(min(caxis)));               % min value in flow
 V_max = ceil(max(caxis));               % max value in flow

 % this portion changes the colors of the cylinder sections
 n = 1000;

 figure(F)
 colorbar

 fh = gcf();
 axh = findall(fh, 'Type','Axes');
 cbh = findall(fh, 'Type', 'ColorBar');

 M1prime = 1/3*V_min;
 M2prime = 1/2*V_max;

 caxis([M1prime,M2prime])

 % I have adapted the code for making your own interpolated colormap here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851050/how-to-create-an-interpolated-colormap-or-color-palette-from-two-colors
 % Set white to be zero with blue as negative and red as positive
 n0 = floor(interp1([M1prime,M2prime],[1,n],0));    % interpolate color index to zero

 nN2 = floor(interp1([M1prime,M2prime],[1,n],iso-1));       % blue to cyan
 nN1 = floor(interp1([M1prime,M2prime],[1,n],iso));       % cyan to white
 nP1 = floor(interp1([M1prime,M2prime],[1,n],-iso));      % white to yellow
 nP2 = floor(interp1([M1prime,M2prime],[1,n],-(iso-1)));      % yellow to red

 cmap = zeros(5,3);
 cmap(1,:) = [0 0 1];   %// color first row - blue
 cmap(2,:) = [0 1 1];    % cyan
 cmap(3,:) = [1 1 1];   %// color 1/2*nth row - white
 cmap(4,:) = [1 1 0];    % yellow
 cmap(5,:) = [1 0 0];   %// color nth row - red

 [xcs,ycs] = meshgrid(1:3,1:n);  %// mesh of indices

 cmapN = interp2(xcs([1,nN2,nN1],:),ycs([1,nN2,nN1],:),[cmap(1:2,:);cmap(2,:)],xcs,ycs);         %// interpolate blue to cyan
 cmapN(nN1+1:end,:) = [];

 cmapZ1 = interp2(xcs([nN1+1,nN1+1+floor((n0-(nN1+1))/2),n0],:),ycs([nN1+1,nN1+1+floor((n0-(nN1+1))/2),n0],:),[cmap(2:3,:);cmap(3,:)],xcs,ycs);      %// interpolate cyan to white    
 cmapZ1(1:nN1,:) = [];   Lz1 = length(cmapZ1);
 cmapZ1(Lz1-(n-n0)+1:Lz1,:) = [];

 cmapZ2 = interp2(xcs([n0+1,n0+1+floor((nP1-(n0+1))/2),nP1],:),ycs([n0+1,n0+1+floor((nP1-(n0+1))/2),nP1],:),[cmap(3,:);cmap(3:4,:)],xcs,ycs);          %// interpolate white to yellow
 cmapZ2(1:n0,:) = [];    Lz2 = length(cmapZ2);
 cmapZ2(Lz2-(n-nP1)+1:Lz2,:) = [];

 cmapP = interp2(xcs([nP1+1,nP2,n],:),ycs([nP1+1,nP2,n],:),[cmap(4,:);cmap(4:5,:)],xcs,ycs);         %// interpolate yellow to red
 cmapP(1:nP1,:) = [];

 cmapNtot = [cmapN;cmapZ1];
 cmapPtot = [cmapZ2;cmapP];

 cmap = [cmapNtot;cmapPtot];
 colormap(cmap) %// set color map

  Lia = ismember(cmap,[1 1 1],'rows');
  alpha_map = double((~Lia)');   

  Vsli.AlphaData = alpha_map;
```

Comment: You will need to show us how to plot one or two of those for us to be able to help. Also, are you sure your white is [1,1,1] and not [0.9999, 0.9999, 0.99999] ?

Comment: Yes white is exactly [1 1 1] there other reasons where I transition from cyan to white or white to yellow. I will make the necessary corrections in an edit.

Comment: That should be regions, not reasons.

Comment: Hi, please, try to add a [mcve]. We dont need the full code, just enough to reproduce a piece of it. We need some sample data, not necesarily your data

Comment: You can just use `flow` which I included. I'll try to change what I provided to a minimal reproducible example.